# Reading and Printing Wide Character String

Tags: c

I want to read and print the uppercase version of wide characters in c.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    wchar_t sentence[100];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    void Edit(wchar_t str[]);

    printf("Enter sentence -> ");
    wscanf(L"%[^\n]ls", sentence);

    Edit(sentence);
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Edit(wchar_t str[]){
    int i = -1;
    while(str[++i])
        if(iswalpha(str[i]))    //get rid of whitespaces and other characters
            putwchar(towupper(str[i]));
}
```

It seems that the problem resides in wscanf in fact if I initialize the string like this:

```
wchar_t sentence[] = L"è";
```

And the Edit it without reading or asking for a string, it works.

I am using Windows 10, and USA international Keyboard Input,so to make 'è', I have to press ` + e. But I also tried to copy and paste it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, but doesn't work. I am using MINGW with GCC compiler version 6.3.0. I also tried this with my MacBook and doesn't work.

The problem is that if I input "kèy", I want "KÈY" as output. Instead, I get "KSY". I don't know why 'è' outputs 'S' but I tried with other vocals and I get same random characters. However, if I initialize the string as "kèy", I get "KÈY".

**Update**

I edited wscanf as:

```
wscanf(L"%ls", sentence);
```

And it works on my MacBook, but not on windows! Also in this way I can't input spaces, because wscanf stops at the first space.

**Update 2**

I found something really interesting:
Using this snippet:

```
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t frase[100];

    fwide(stdin, 1);
    wscanf(L"%ls", frase);
    wprintf(L"%ls", frase);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I found [this table](http://redgrittybrick.org/charsets.html) and when I input 'è' I get S, which is what the Win column describes. So I tried to input Þ and I got 'è'! I think the problem is with the codes of the cmd, I am using page code: 850

**I found a solution**
I used `system("chcp 1252")` to change character set and it WORKED!

Comment: Is the standard input (stdin) actually a wide character stream?

Comment: Your code works fine here. What is your input? And what exactly _is_ the problem?

Comment: On Linux, it should work if you are using a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: @IanAbbott wscanf take stdin input as wide characters, I don't know what's the point of your comment

Comment: @Giulio please [edit]  your question and put all relevant clarifications _there_

Comment: I'm not sure what you need for Windows, but mixing `char` and `wchar_t` functions on the same `FILE *` is a bad idea. E.g. you are using `printf` and `putwchar` on stdout, and you are using `getchar` and `wscanf` on stdin.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Try `wscanf(L"%l[^\n]", sentence);`

Comment: @IanAbbott It works! But only on my macbook :( What could be the problem on windows?

Comment: Your question is rather: _Why does `wscanf(L"%[^\n]ls", sentence);` transform all accentuated letters into some other letter, e.g. `è` is transformed into `Š`?_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes. I solved the problem on linux and made it work properly thanks to Ian Abbot, but on Windows I don't know why it doesn't work. (The code is the same on both O.S)

Comment: I can't make it work on Windows...

Comment: Perhaps try to use `fwide()` to set `stdin` to wide character mode.

Comment: @fuz tried with `fwide(stdin, 1);` but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `wscanf` use `fgetws` - this will allow you to read white space and protect against buffer overflow. In general its best practice (especially when using user supplied input) to protect against buffer overflow. I edited your code below.

```
int main(){
    wchar_t sentence[100];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    void Edit(wchar_t str[]);

    printf("Enter sentence -> ");
    fgetws(sentence,100,stdin);

    Edit(sentence);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Edit(wchar_t str[]){
    int i = -1;
    while(str[++i])
        if(iswalpha(str[i]))    //get rid of whitespaces and other characters
            putwchar(towupper(str[i]));
}
```

You may also want to define your buffer size, and properly allocate and free memory as well.